# How to create .fmt file, and export data into multiple tables from mixed-input file

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, bcp

Am trying to set up a .fmt file using the bcp utility. I have been successfully able to create this before thus (using the table that data gets exported to as input):

bcp cmsDatabase.dbo.Table1 format nul -T -c -f Table1Format.fmt

```
9.0
3
1       SQLCHAR       0       12      "\t"     1     Col1_Table1      ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     "\t"     2     Col2_Table1      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       0       "\t"     3     Col3_Table1      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Table1 from which it was created:
Col1_Table1 int (primary key)
Col2_Table1 nvarchar(50)
Col3_Table1 nvar

Now I'm facing an issue. I have the input .txt/.csv file (delimited flat file) with data that will not be imported directly into one table, it has to go into many tables (AND, one directly goes into rows, other data needs to be input into columns of table2), Example Input File's data:

```
"Col1_Table1x" "Col2_Table1x" "Col3_Table1x" "Col1_Table2x, Col1_Table2y, Col1_Table2z"
```

Update:
In the above file, values have to go into:

```
Col1_Tablex -> Col1_Table1 column of Table1
Col2_Tablex -> Col2_Table1 column of Table1
Col3_Table1x ->  Col3_Table1 column of Table1
```

Table1:

```
Col1_Table1   Col2_Table1   Col3_Table1
-------------------------------------------
Col1_Table1x   Col2_Table1x   Col3_Table1x
```

Till here, I can get it to work.

**What I'm trying to figure out:**

"Col1_Table2, Col1_Table2, Col1_Table2, ....." -> Multiple records to be placed in Table2, populating Col_Table2 with the comma-seperated values, and 
with Col1_Table1 as foreign key.

i.e Table2 should have

```
    Col1_Table1      Col1_Table2
----------------------------------------------
    Col1_Table1x    Col1_Table2x
    Col1_Table1x    Col1_Table2y
    Col1_Table1x    Col1_Table2z
```

where Col1_Table2 needs to go as rows into Table2 (and is comma seperated), and Col1_Table1 is a foreign key for Table2 so it needs to be copied over too.

Is there a way to create a .fmt file that will allow this kind of mixed-input to be copied over?

Additional details: Each time I need to load up the tables from this input file, I can truncate all old data and re-populate. Any of the columns can have special characters like <, " , & etc. so is there a way to handle that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the volume of data is small/moderate then can you simply import the data into a staging table and import to the two tables in a different step.

Also you could skip few columns in the data file by using two different format files and using them to insert into different tables skipping the columns from other tables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187908.aspx

Coming to special characters, the only good way to solve this is use multiple column delimiters. I am in the music industry, so sometimes I use 3 different column delimiters to import the data correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I like the idea of putting data into a temporary table that's used to import into the other two actual tables. I will be provided only one input file, so my main concern is if there is a way of getting all the data in "Col1_Table2, Col1_Table2, ..." into different rows/another table each? I can create two format files too, one as mentioned in the question, and the other based on the other table. Is there still a way to know which data needs to go into which tables?

Comment: >>Is there still a way to know which data needs to go into which tables?  You need to determine that information and we can't do that programatically.

Comment: I have edited my question a little bit the file input is the same, the table2 rows come in comma-seperated and the others are tab/quotation seperated.